# Why doesn't this regex capture reach the end of the string?

Tags: python, regex

I have some text, a block with address and phone numbers, that looks like:

```
import re
text = 'John Doe Inc - Real Estate Brokers\n1234 Shaky Bridge Road, '\
       '\n Suite 123, \nDallas, TX 12345\n\nTel: 123-456-7890\n\t\t'\
       '\n\t\tCell: 234-567-8901'
```

I just want to keep everything before "`Tel:`" (i.e. the address, not the phone numbers).

I tried removing "`Tel:`" and everything after it.

```
re.sub('Tel:.*','',text)

# Returns:
# 'John Doe Inc - Real Estate Brokers\n1234 Shaky Bridge Road, \n Suite 123, \nDallas, TX 12345\n\n\n\t\t\n\t\tCell: 234-567-8901'
```

However, this only removes "`Tel: 123-456-7890`".  The substring that is removed does not extend through the end of the string.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `flags=re.DOTALL`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that works.  Feel free to answer.